# How to handle ASP.NET configuration changes in a Sitecore project that uses TDS?

Tags: web-config, sitecore, sitecore7, tds

I have a Sitecore Visual Studio project that is using Team Development for Sitecore and is set up according to best practices outlined in this article: http://jockstothecore.com/setting-up-a-sitecore-solution-part-1-visual-studio-and-projects/.  It has a web project that lives outside of the Sitecore root and at build time it copies the necessary files over to my local Sitecore installation.  It works great.  I know that if I have changes that need to be made to the Sitecore configuration I can do that using include files in the App_Config/Include folder and those changes will also be copied over to my local Sitecore installation and will be incorporated in to the Sitecore site.  However, what do I do if I need to make other changes to the ASP.NET configuration? (non-Sitecore config)  According to the article I referenced above I can't have a web.config file in my web project because at build time it would copy that file over my web.config in my Sitecore installation and that would mess everything up.  I'm looking for some way to be able to make ASP.NET config changes in my local web project and at build time have those config changes propogate over to my Sitecore installation.  Ideally I don't want to touch the web.config file in the local Sitecore installation.  One of the goals of this setup is to not have any of the local Sitecore files in source control and be able to completely wipe out and re-install the local Sitecore installation at any time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot patch asp.net configuration like you would sitecore config sections using include files. Having said that, I would add web.config to VS and use Slow Cheetah to add config transforms per build configuration per environment. I don't see any harm in adding config files to source control especially when you have custom settings for each environment.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can't do that in my current configuration. The Sitecore installation is at C:\mySitecoreSite.  The VS solution is in C:\myVSSolution.  Only files in myVSSolution are in source control.  At build time TDS will copy over files from myVSSolution to mySitecoreSite.  If I have a web.config in myVSSolution, then it will overwrite the web.config file in mySitecoreSite and the Sitecore site won't work.

Comment: I usually create a separate project in my solution for configuration files to be deployed using TDS. This project obviously includes the app_config deployable files but is also includes a copy of the web config from the sitecore instance. I can then apply transforms to which ever config files need them and let TDS do file replacements.